# How use symbol sharp (#) with BulletList Value inside folder?

Tags: c#, absolute

The anchor is not working in this case, why?:

```
    public void TabsCliente() {

        ulCliente.Items.Add(new ListItem(Resources.Titulos.tlCadastroCliente, "#tabCadastrarCliente"));

    }


<ul id="ulCliente">
<li><a href="../Controles/#tabCadastrarCliente">Cadastrar Cliente</a></li>
```

it should look like:

```
<ul id="ulCliente">
<li><a href="#tabCadastrarCliente">Cadastrar Cliente</a></li>
```

Help me! Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your C# code, change `"#tabCadastrarCliente"` to `"/#tabCadastrarCliente"`.